# Real Mode x86 simulator similar to SPIM?

Tags: x86, spim, real-mode

I am looking for a Real Mode x86 simulator similar in principle to the MIPS32 simulator ["SPIM"](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/spim.html).

Ideally, it would also support 286 Protected Mode (32 bit Protected Mode is less important).

Anyone know such a beast?

Comment: What's wrong with Bochs, DosBox, QEMU, etc etc?

Comment: They are emulators for running binaries. I am looking for a simulator for the assembly language, like SPIM.

Comment: Like [emu8086](http://www.emu8086.com/)?

Comment: That looks like the thing. I'll have to try it tomorrow. Ta.

Comment: Potentially irrelevant, however, are you not running a box with x86 architecture? That's relatively impressive :p

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point.